# Decode dynamic value of class using Codable

Tags: swift, algolia, codable

I have the following classes:

```
class AlgoliaLocation: Codable {

    var id: String
    var address: String?
    var otherInfo: String?
}

struct AlgoliaHit<T: AlgoliaLocation>: Codable {
    var highlightResult: [T.CodingKeys : [AlgoliaHighlightResult]]
    var coordintates: [AlgoliaCoordinate]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case highlightResult = "_highlightResult"
        case coordinates = "_geoloc"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let temp = try? container.decode([T.CodingKeys : AlgoliaHighlightResult].self,
                                                   forKey: .highlightResult) {
        var highlightResult = [T.CodingKeys : [AlgoliaHighlightResult]]()
        for (key, value) in temp {
            highlightResult[key] = [value]
        }
        self.highlightResult = highlightResult
    } else {
        highlightResult = try container.decode([ T.CodingKeys : [AlgoliaHighlightResult]].self,
                                                forKey: .highlightResult)
    }
}
```

I got stuck decoding the value of `highlightResult` because the value of the coding key can either be an array like defined in the model of `AlgoliaHit` class or directly the object of type `AlgoliaHighlightResult`. So each key from the `AlgoliaLocation.CodingKeys` can either be of type `[AlgoliaHighlightResult]` or `AlgoliaHighlightResult` and I need a way to loop through through each dynamic key when decoding and map the value to an array when it is not an array. I tried to decode all as array values and all as object values but they alternate and a key can be either one of them (array or object). Thank you!
In case something is not clear this is what I am trying to map:
[Algolia JSON](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/search/?language=json#method-response-_highlightresult).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to accomplish this using a nested container which I could use to iterate through the dynamic keys and check each type:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let highlightResultContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: T.CodingKeys.self, forKey: .highlightResult)

    var highlightResult = [T.CodingKeys : [AlgoliaHighlightResult]]()

    for highlightResultKey in highlightResultContainer.allKeys {
        if let value = try? highlightResultContainer.decode(AlgoliaHighlightResult.self,
                                                            forKey: highlightResultKey) {
            highlightResult[highlightResultKey] = [value]
        } else {
            let value = try highlightResultContainer.decode([AlgoliaHighlightResult].self,
                                                            forKey: highlightResultKey)
            highlightResult[highlightResultKey] = value
        }
    }
    self.highlightResult = highlightResult
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can handle it init(from decoder: Decoder) methods

```
    if let objHits =  try values.decodeIfPresent(Hits.self, forKey: .hits) {
        hits = [objHits]
    } else {
        hits = try values.decodeIfPresent([Hits].self, forKey: .hits)
    }
```

> I will follow, the below code snippet to parse it correctly.

```
import Foundation
struct algolia : Codable {
let hits : [Hits]?
let page : Int?
let nbHits : Int?
let nbPages : Int?
let hitsPerPage : Int?
let processingTimeMS : Int?
let query : String?
let params : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case hits = "hits"
    case page = "page"
    case nbHits = "nbHits"
    case nbPages = "nbPages"
    case hitsPerPage = "hitsPerPage"
    case processingTimeMS = "processingTimeMS"
    case query = "query"
    case params = "params"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let objHits =  try values.decodeIfPresent(Hits.self, forKey: .hits) {
        hits = [objHits]
    } else {
        hits = try values.decodeIfPresent([Hits].self, forKey: .hits)
    }
    page = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .page)
    nbHits = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .nbHits)
    nbPages = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .nbPages)
    hitsPerPage = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .hitsPerPage)
    processingTimeMS = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .processingTimeMS)
    query = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .query)
    params = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .params)
}}
struct Hits : Codable {
let firstname : String?
let lastname : String?
let objectID : String?
let _highlightResult : _highlightResult?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case firstname = "firstname"
    case lastname = "lastname"
    case objectID = "objectID"
    case _highlightResult = "_highlightResult"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    firstname = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstname)
    lastname = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastname)
    objectID = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .objectID)
    _highlightResult = try values.decodeIfPresent(_highlightResult.self, forKey: ._highlightResult)
}}
struct Firstname : Codable {
let value : String?
let matchLevel : String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case value = "value"
    case matchLevel = "matchLevel"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    value = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .value)
    matchLevel = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .matchLevel)
}}
struct _highlightResult : Codable {
let firstname : Firstname?
let lastname : Lastname?
let company : Company?
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case firstname = "firstname"
    case lastname = "lastname"
    case company = "company"
}
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    firstname = try values.decodeIfPresent(Firstname.self, forKey: .firstname)
    lastname = try values.decodeIfPresent(Lastname.self, forKey: .lastname)
    company = try values.decodeIfPresent(Company.self, forKey: .company)
}}
```

**In your view controller use below code**

```
    func jsonToCodable<T: Codable>(json: [String: Any], codable: T.Type) -> T? {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let codable = try decoder.decode(codable, from: data)
        return codable

    } catch {
        print("*/ json failed */")
        print(error)
        //print(error.localizedDescription)
        print(json)
    }
    return nil
}
 if let algoliaObject = jsonToCodable(json: jsonictionary, codable: algolia.self) {// using optional chaining access _highlightResult }
```

Comment: The problem on my side and referencing your example, on my side the properties that you have (firstname, lastname, company) will be inferred dynamically depending on diferent models that's why for now I have  AlgoliaHit<T: AlgoliaLocation> because currently I am trying to map an AlgoliaLocation type object. so the keys will be taken from the specified generic type but the issues is that the properties (for example what you have: fristname, lastname, company) can be either Array of Firstname or Firstname like in your example, I am not sure how to check that when the keys are dynamically taken.

Comment: can you add all types of JSON you're expecting?